# Can a person be charged the same as if they were crossing the international border at internal checkpoints, or what can they be charged with?

Tags: fourth-amendment, borders

Building off [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/95813/how-do-internal-border-checkpoints-with-warrantless-searches-fit-with-the-4th-am), if a person is travelling with something that is for personal use that wouldn't be allowed across the border, would they be charged as if they were crossing the international border? Whereas they wouldn't have been searched if they were traveling elsewhere. Or more generally, what could they be charged with? Is it admissible if it had nothing to do with the border (e.g. something that generally comes from somewhere internally, far from the border)? There is the issue also of (state legal) cannabis transporters in southern California, it's not clear to me if they are charged when their goods are just seized at times. To be clear, internal checkpoints are treated like the real border, I'm just wondering the outcomes, i.e. charges.

Comment: Do you have an example of something that the US would **not** allow you to bring across the border, yet would otherwise be perfectly legal to transport in your car?

Comment: In California, various fruits and veg probably, but in that case it would be a question of where it came from, if not found before. But I'm really asking about how someone could be caught with something only because of the internal border checkpoint, like they wouldn't have crossed the border with it, as in the border had nothing to do with their actions, as somewhat shown by it being personal use. But specific in California, having some weed wouldn't be allowed across the border, but internally is, but that's due to differing laws federal and state.

Comment: So there may be specific cases, but it's like a question of admissibility in court also. Like searches without warrants normally wouldn't produce admissible evidence.

Comment: California has borders checking for fruit or veg from any state though also.

Comment: OK, but wouldn't the burden of proof be on the border patrol to provide evidence that it was brought across the border?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works, that's what I'm asking.

Comment: Innocent until proven guilty is a cornerstone of our legal system, and the burden of proof is on the prosecution.  If you have an apple on your front seat and they want to charge you with bringing it across the border they will have to prove you crossed the border with it in court.  Somebody will likely provide a better answer, but if nobody does I will expand this into an answer later...

Comment: I don't think they actually check much for fruit and veg internally. Those are more on the actual border themselves.

Comment: The internal checkpoints are sometimes well past many farm fields.

Comment: CBP, being a federal agency, enforces federal laws - irrespective (I would imagine) of the state in which they're acting. So if you're transporting cannabis in California and you're within the 100 mile border enforcement zone, you probably shouldn't be surprised if CBP stops you and steals all your stash - since it's still illegal at the federal level.

Comment: I know they take it, at least sometimes, I'm wondering what charges occur, if they do.

Comment: Possession, smuggling, intent to distribute, come to mind...

Comment: Yeah but if the possession is unrelated to the border, it's still admissible?

Comment: I know searches with warrants can pick up other evidence if come across as part of a normal search, is it the same with warrantless?

Comment: And yeah, is there a border related charge if it isn't across the border? E.g. smuggling, especially if it's for personal use and didn't originate across the border.

Comment: Not to mention possession where in a state where it's legal.

Comment: Like say someone from northern california visits southern california and has a stem of something they picked in northern california that only grows there. They are searched enough to where it's found, though no dogs detected it even. They could be charged for that?

Comment: You are just rehashing a lot of the same points in your comments. Whether or not a federal agency responsible for customs and immigration can arrest you for possession of a substance you are transporting intrastate, (have NOT crossed the border) and "legally" in accordance to local jurisdiction is a *good question*. I'd suggest you clean up your comments, be patient, and give someone a chance to answer. I will be happy to delete mine as well...

Comment: @MichaelHall Border Patrol officers at internal checkpoints will arrest on federal possession if the amount possessed meets the federal threshold for prosecution; they'll typically pass the suspect and the evidence to state or local authorities if the amount is below the threshold.  They generally will not pursue smuggling charges because they generally will not have evidence that the substance was smuggled.  In brief, they can pursue crimes that they become aware of during a stop, but the fact that they're Border Patrol officers doesn't turn the incident into a border crossing.

Comment: @phoog, I wasn’t suggesting that the fact they are border patrol officers turns the incident into a border crossing, in fact I was trying to infer the opposite was the case.  If my use of the word “smuggling” as a *possible* charge led you to believe otherwise, it was in the context of domestic smuggling.  (Unless “smuggling” is strictly defined as international only?)

Answer (score 2):

> would they be charged as if they were crossing the international border?

No.  Or rather, maybe they would, but if the border patrol had no actual evidence of an actual border crossing then the prosecutor would probably decline to prosecute any such charges, the court would dismiss the charges, or the finder of fact would render a verdict of *not guilty.*

But there are plenty of charges available that don't include entry into the US as an element.  There are laws against transporting illegal aliens within the US and there are laws against possessing cannabis within the US.

One thought experiment that serves to distinguish internal checkpoints from ports of entry is to think about less serious violations at ports of entry.  If you buy something for $20,000 abroad, for example, you are supposed to declare it when you return to the US and pay customs duty.  If you don't declare it and then they discover it during a search, you will suffer some negative consequences.  But if you appear at a border checkpoint and they find a $20,000 necklace in your glove compartment, and you have a receipt showing that you just bought it (in the US), there is no violation.

People sometimes confuse the inland checkpoints with the "border search exception."  The border search exception does *not* apply at internal immigration checkpoints.  The border search exception allows customs agents to search you and your belongings when you're crossing an international border *without any suspicion of a crime whatsoever.*  At an internal checkpoint, there has to be probable cause to search your vehicle (or consent).

You can read about drug-sniffing dogs being used at checkpoint stops to "manufacture" probable cause -- that is, the officer supposedly decides that it would be a good idea to search a car, but there are no circumstances that give probable cause, so they bring the dog and claim (perhaps falsely) that the dog has "alerted," indicating the presence of drugs in the vehicle.  By contrast, you never read about this at the border, because at the border *agents don't need probable cause to search vehicles.*  They use the dogs to help them to decide which vehicles to search and to help them find the things they're searching for.